# Hibernate: HQL delete from embedded map

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-4.x, hql-delete

I want to delete entries from an embedded map. If the object `CategoryTag` is deleted, I want to execute a HQL query in an interceptor, which deletes the entries from a map:

**'Product' model:**

```
@NotNull
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "producttag", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
protected Map<CategoryTag, String> tags = new HashMap<CategoryTag, String>();
```

I am kinda blank how i can write the HQL query. It starts with the problem, that I do not know how to reference the map in a delete query. `delete Product.tags t where t.key = :tag` fails with an `Product.tags is not mapped` exception.

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Tags is not entity.

```
A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. It does not cascade to related entities.
```

This is why you are getting the error. The correct way is to load Entity, update its collection and then save this object.

```
Product p = session.load(Product.class, id);
p.removeTags(tag);
session.flush();
```

Comment: `CategoryTag` does not have a reference to `Product`, so it basically does not know, which products are using it. So in order to do it the way you suggested, I would have to select all products which contain the tag and then delete it in a loop, as you suggested. However, I wonder if there is a way to do it with one simple statement. I can do it with a native query: `delete from producttag where tags_KEY = :tag` but this causes caching problems, so I was wondering if there was a way to do it in HQL.

Comment: I believe you still need to do the way I told you and this way will help you to skip caching problems.